# Does $f(z) = \sin(\frac{1}{z})$ have infinitely many zeroes in the unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does $f(z) = \sin(\frac{1}{z})$ have infinitely many zeroes in the unit disk? If so can someone please explain how?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $z=\frac1{n\pi}$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$, what is $f(z)$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider restricting the function to $\{\,z \mid Re(z)\in[-1,1]\text{ and}\,Im(z)=0\}$. Does this function look familiar? What do you know about the zeros of this function on the interval?